# Android playing sounds from a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I've found multiple similar posts but have been unable to resolve so posting my code for help.

I have 3 fragments that use a ViewPager with a PagerAdapter to allow for swiping between fragments.  This project started with no fragments and I was able to play sounds from buttons clicked all from MainActivity.

Here's the code that worked.

MainActivity

```
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer example1Sound;
    MediaPlayer example2Sound;
    MediaPlayer example3Sound;
    MediaPlayer example4Sound;
    MediaPlayer example5Sound;
    MediaPlayer example6Sound;
    MediaPlayer example7Sound;
    MediaPlayer example8Sound;
    MediaPlayer example9Sound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    example1Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example1);
    example2Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example2);
    example3Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example3);
    example4Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example4);
    example5Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example5);
    example6Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example6);
    example7Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example7);
    example8Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example8);
    example9Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example9);


    }

    public void playExampleSound1(View view) {
    example1Sound.start();
    }

    public void playExampleSound2(View view) {
    example2Sound.start();
    }

    public void playExampleSound3(View view) {
    example3Sound.start();
    }

    public void playExampleSound4(View view) {
    example4Sound.start();
    }

    public void playExampleSound5(View view) {
    example5Sound.start();
    }

    public void playExampleSound6(View view) {
    example6Sound.start();
    }

    public void playExampleSound7(View view) {
    example7Sound.start();
    }

    public void playExampleSound8(View view) {
    example8Sound.start();
    }

    public void playExampleSound9(View view) {
    example9Sound.start();
    }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.anjosoft.MainActivity">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="@drawable/button1"
            android:onClick="playExampleSound1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button2"
            android:onClick="playExampleSound2" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="@drawable/button3"
            android:onClick="playExampleSound3" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="@drawable/button4"
            android:onClick="playExampleSound4" />

         <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button5"
            android:onClick="playExampleSound5" />

         <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="@drawable/button6"
            android:onClick="playExampleSound6" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="@drawable/button7"
            android:onClick="playExampleSound7" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button8"
            android:onClick="playExampleSound8" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="@drawable/button9"
            android:onClick="playExampleSound9" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send Sound"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_column="1" />
     </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I know it's not pretty.  Should have made an array but nevertheless it worked.

So here's my problem.  Using the same ideology I tied the same thing with fragment.

MainActivity.java

```
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager viewpager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewpager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter padapter = new       PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewpager.setAdapter(padapter);
    }
    }
```

PagerAdapter.java

```
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new FragmentOne();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentTwo();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentThree();
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

FragmentOne.java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    MediaPlayer example1Sound;
    MediaPlayer example2Sound;
    MediaPlayer example3Sound;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        example1Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this.getActivity(), R.raw.example1);
        example2Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this.getActivity(), R.raw.example2);
        example3Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this.getActivity(), R.raw.example3);


        return    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout,container,false);


    }

    public void playExampleSound1(View view){
        example1Sound.start();
    }

    public void playExampleSound2(View view) {
        example2Sound.start();
    }

    public void playExampleSound3(View view) {
        example3Sound.start();
    }
 }
```

fragnment_one_layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"          android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f70808">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:background="@drawable/button1"
                android:onClick="playExampleSound1"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button2" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:background="@drawable/button3" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Clicking on imagebutton crashes the app.  I know the MediaPlayer can work inside the app because I tested inserting example1Sound.start(); like this...

Snippet from FragmentOne.java

```
       example1Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this.getActivity(), R.raw.example1);
       example2Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this.getActivity(), R.raw.example2);
       example3Sound = MediaPlayer.create(this.getActivity(), R.raw.example3);
       example1Sound.start();
```

The sound plays when the fragment loads.  How do I get the onclick to work?

Comment: also add main thing, i.e. error log

Comment: It's just on the Emulation.  When I click button 1 says "Unfortunately, SwipeDemo has stopped." with an  OK to click.

Answer (score 0):

You can use   onClickListeners   for each button, it works.

I think,   fragnment_one_layout.xml    is linked to   FragmentOne.java   using inflater 
but the    fragnment_one_layout.xml    has no access to    FragmentOne.java   , and hence 
the statement   onClick="methodName"   is not able to access the desired method.
  mediaPlayer   object has no connection with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one function that redirect sound from Activity to Fragment! 
in Activity

```
 fun onSound(sound:Int){
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,soundFile)
    mp.start
 }
```

from fragment

```
 onResume{
   (activity as ActivityName).onSound(R.raw.sound)

}
```